# Unicode character code for "Modifier Letter Low Right Arrow"

Tags: unicode

what is the character code for "**Modifier Letter Low Right Arrow**" symbol ?

Please help me out as i am not able to find it anywhere since 2 days. everywhere they have given the code for "Modifier Letter Low Left Arrow" which is **02FF** but not the right arrow .

Thanks

Comment: Would any of these help? http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html

Comment: Why do you need it. Maybe there's another way.

Comment: Millie I'll have to use the same modifier since it's already used in the project I'm working on. also I don't know the character code used by them. So trying to figure it out on my own.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about looking up a value in a table that is public available on the Internet from official sources. WTF is wrong with people? Can't they search these days? FFS, I'm 26, don't make me go all "get off my lawn" on you.

Comment: It would be a serious failing of Google if it ever links to this page instead of the actual answer.

Comment: I can see the usecase. A person has used a webding character in a design one now needs to transform into a design. It looks exactly like this arrow, but is turned the other way. *search continues*

Answer (score 3):

"Modifier Letter Low Left Arrow" is a character in the [Spacing Modifier Letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters) block. It has a [specific usage in a phonetic system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uralic_Phonetic_Alphabet). I don't believe the counterpart "Modifier Letter Low Right Arrow" exist.

Comment: It’s “modifier”, not “modified”. The word “modifier” reflects the usage that you mention. Modifier letters are characters used as parts of words (being letters that way) to modify the meaning of other characters, such as to indicate a variant of sound (phonetic value).